# How do I get the string value from an enum if the string is different than the enum member?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum that I'd like to parse like an object. I really like how the Swift programming language you just use the .rawValue to get the string value of an enum member `(i.e. HelloWorld.one.rawValue = "this is one")` but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Typescript.

```
enum HelloWorld { 
    one = "this is one",
    two = "two",
    three = "the third"
}

const getStringFromEnum = (num: HelloWorld) => {
  return HelloWorld[num]
};
```

If I input `HelloWorld.one` to the getSringFromEnum function, I'd like to output "this is one" but I get the error that `Property '[HelloWorld.one]' does not exist on type 'typeof HelloWorld'.`

Comment: Oops, I just realized that all I had to do was `return num.valueOf()` - this solved my question. Should I delete the question now since it's a simple answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if enums are the best approach for what you are trying to do. Enums basically provide syntactic sugar for basic Dictionary types.

```
enum HelloWorld { 
    one = "this is one",
    two = "two",
    three = "the third"
}
```

transpiles to something like

```
const HelloWorld {
    one: "this is one",
    two: "two",
    three: "the third",
    "this is one": "one",
    two = "two",
    "the third": "three"
}
```

allowing for easy back-and-forth lookup of its keys and values. There is no need for a `getStringFromEnum` function, you can simply use `HelloWorld.one` from anywhere you have imported your enum.

If you need a lookup function, but don't need the backwards lookup, it might be better to use a variable instead of an enum

```
const helloWorld = { 
    one: "this is one",
    two: "two",
    three: "the third"
}

function getStringFromEnum(num: keyof typeof helloWorld): string {
  return helloWorld[num];
};
```

Of course helloWorld could be typed beforehand, removing the need for `typeof helloWorld`. Otherwise, you're right. You could use

```
function getStringFromEnum(num: HelloWorld): string {
    return num.valueOf();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra context here, You're probably right about using a dictionary rather than an enum in this case but I dig the fact that it adds some warning like in Switches if I forget a case.

Comment: @mpc75 Absolutely, the warinings in switches saved my ass a couple of times. But the `keyof typeof helloWorld` should provide the same functionality in terms of warnings. if you know beforehand what entries your dictionary will have, you cold also define a type / interface for it. Have a look at [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt), maybe it could be useful in your case